# Same service, different servers yield different result

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm accessing the same service on different servers. Request is the same, however the response are not. One yields to successful call, why the other one threw a type initialized exemption.

What could be the contributing factor for a failure call?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

After additional logging to get the inner exemption, it is looking for Caching.Client.dll

However, the weird stuff is same codes, services and dlls were deployed in different servers. The result is positive in server A,B,C but not in D and E.

Comment: That's caused by not 1) catching the exception 2) not calling ToString on it 3) not logging the result of this and 4) not adding it to your question in a well-formatted [edit].  You did something wrong, it broke on startup. Could be one of a million things.

Comment: Is Caching.Client.dll in the bin folder or GACed on the server?

Comment: @Will, thanks for this :)

Comment: @Tim - the said dll is not GACed, thank you also! It is the missing link :)

Comment: You're welcome :)   Note that you don't need to GAC the DLL - you can just drop in the bin of the service for simplicity.

Comment: Tada!  @Tim you should add an answer so OP can close this out.

Answer (score 0):

The service is looking for `Caching.Client.dll` and is not finding it.  Either it's not in the bin of the service, or its not GACed on the server.

Dropping the DLL in the bin of the service should resolve the issue.  You could also GAC the DLL (it it's a .NET assembly), but that has additional requirements, so dropping it in the bin is the simplest approach.